# Activeadmin: Setting the default prompt for all select fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I have a two select fields and their default options are blank so I would like to set all of them to 'Choose one'. I can do it for individual fields but I want to do it in the config somehow (avoiding the redundancy).

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Item" do
      f.input :field_1, :prompt => 'Choose one', :foo
      f.input :field_2, :prompt => 'Choose one', :bar
    end
  end
```

How do I do this? :)

Edit: These prompts would be used on many forms. It really needs to be a config thing.

Comment: It will be a bit of work, but this seems to provide an example for what you need: http://yob.id.au/2010/08/19/extending-formtastic.html  You can create your own formtastic input type, by subclassing the right type of field. In that subclass you can set your prompt once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a array:

```
fields = [:field_1, :field2]

  form do |f|
      f.inputs "Item" do
        fields.each { |field| f.input field, :prompt => 'Choose one' }        
      end
  end
```

Comment: Yes, this would help but I would have these on other forms. I was not clear about this and I will edit my question. Thanks!